# How to add content dynamically using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two columns on my page.

Left column has list of add button and right column is empty.

I want add append content to right side based on button click(left side buttons).

These content must be rendered using Angular (using angular binding) before appending to the DOM.

I search a lot but did't got satisfying info.

I am new to [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/).

Example:

content is

```
 <tr>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" name="name1" value={{name}}> </td>
    <td> {{ text }} </td>
</tr>
```

I want add above tr in right side column (which have empty table initially).

Comment: these content must be rendered using Angular (using angular binding) before appending to dom. What do you mean here ? The content is html ?

Comment: can you post the code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: @maxisam. Sorry for confusion. content is angular template (html).

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/ADukg/ fork it and add what you have tried so far. It's easier for people to help if they have a concrete starting point

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use ng-view and route to achieve this.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJvxXj?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', [])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/btnA', { templateUrl: 'btnA.html', controller: btnACtrl })

                            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/btnB' });
          }]);

function btnACtrl($scope){
   $scope.text = 'Hello world !' ;
}
```

Comment: Also you can use ng-include directive http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude